# SwiftUI - Display an array of Image

Tags: swiftui

I'm using Apple's VisionKit and storing the images in both an `Image` and `Data` array, like so:

```
@State private var image: [Image] = []
@State var imageData : Data = .init(count: 0)
```

And appending the data like this:

```
for imageIndex in imagePerPage! {
  var uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageIndex)
  let converted = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
  image.append(converted)
  imageData.append(uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.00005)!)
}
```

I'm passing the data to another view which is fine, as I can use `print(image.count)` and I get the expected count. However, I'm having issues with iterating over my array and display the images. I use a `ForEach` statement and I get an error nagging me that the data type `Image` must conform to `Hashable` (I'm not using a model/struct)

```
@State var image: [Image]

 ForEach(image.count, id: \.self) { image in
  Image(image)
  .resizable()
  .frame(width: getScreen().width, height: getScreen().height * 0.85)
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}
```

I've even tried a for loop i.e. `for x in images {///}`.

Is there anyway in which I can resolve this issue?

Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ForEach` with a range: `0...10`.

Secondly, your `image` array already holds `Image`s, so you shouldn't need to call `Image` again.

```
ForEach(0..<image.count) { imageIdx in
           image[imageIdx]
           .resizable()
           .frame(width: getScreen().width, height: getScreen().height * 0.85)
           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
```

Now, that being said, I'm a little skeptical of the idea of keeping the `Image` views in the array. I think you'd be better off making your array full of `UIImage` objects and then calling them inside the view with `Image(uiImage:)` inside your view.

Might look more like this:

```
@State var images: [UIImage]
    
var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<images.count) { imageIdx in
           Image(uiImage: images[imageIdx])
           .resizable()
           .frame(width: getScreen().width, height: getScreen().height * 0.85)
           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
}
```

Finally, using `ForEach` with indexes instead of IDs *could* lead to funny issues later if your array gets updated with images as SwiftUI may not know to refresh the view. At that point, it would be better to use a struct wrapper for the images and give them real IDs.